# flutter: Align / pin widgets to bottom of row

Tags: flutter, alignment, flutter-layout

How is it possible to align all items to the bottom of a `Row` in flutter? I have got one widget in the `Row` which changes its height at runtime and due to that, all other widgets of the `Row` automatically center themselves, too. My question is: how do you prevent these other widgets from moving and pin them to the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `CrossAxisAlignment`:

```
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(width: 100, height: 200, color: Colors.red),
    Container(width: 100, height: 300, color: Colors.blue),
    SizedBox(
      width: 100,
      height: 150,
      child: FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
        child: const FlutterLogo(),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Row(
 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
)
```

> I hope you succeeded